# How to get id from String with using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to get only number id from string. result : 123456

```
var text = "http://test/test.aspx?id=123456dfblablalab";
```

EDIT:

Sorry, Another number can be in the text. I want to get first number after id.

```
var text = "http://test/test.aspx?id=123456dfbl4564dsf";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
Regex.Match(text, @"id=(\d+)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context - in this case it looks like you are parsing a Uri and a query string:

```
var text = "http://test/test.aspx?id=123456dfblablalab";
Uri tempUri = new Uri(text);
NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query);
int number = int.Parse(new string(query["id"].TakeWhile(char.IsNumber).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone will give you a C# implementation, but it's along the lines of

```
/[\?\&]id\=([0-9]+)/
```

Which will match either `&id=123456fkhkghkf` or `?id=123456fjgjdfgj` (so it'll get the value wherever it is in the URL) and capture the number as a match.

Comment: For reference, the `?`, `&` and `=` don't need escaping.  At least not in most flavors of regex i've seen -- very little actually needs escaping inside `[]` in any case, and `=` is not a special char.

Comment: Highly likely, but since I don't know C#, I escaped them just in case :) Escaping a char that doesn't need it doesn't do any harm, so better safe than sorry

Comment: Depends on the flavor of regex.  In some flavors, the special chars aren't special unless they *are* escaped.  :P  Vi tends to be particularly annoying in that regard; vim, at least, has like 4 different settings for "magicness".